Does the phrase "O enemy of Allah" implies a disbeliever?
As per an authentic report, Umar bin al khattab said to abu hurayrah "O enemy of Allah"
https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/366526/incident-between-%E2%80%98umar-and-abu-hurayrah-about-public-money
Does this phrase can be construed as takfir (excommunication)?
The prophet while exorcising used the same phrase "get out O enemy of Allah"
And Umar used the same phrase during treaty of hudaybiah to pagans of quraysh.
Relevant to the phrase in question is opinion from reputed mujtahids /scholars that takfir isn't literal.
Ibn qudamah doesn't hold the report if any muslim calls his brother as kafir, one of them is kafir to be literal.
https://al-maktaba.org/book/8463/779#p1
It would be bonus if it is also answered whether the report of Umar using the phrase during his caliphate strengthens the stand of Ibn qudamah?
